Running Java files with Neovim ide
I normally work on java projects and i recentely shifted to neovim from vscode, i have my lsp setup for java and everything but I cant run my files with just "java file.java" since i am using files from other classes. Is there any code runner type plugin that works perfectly in neovim specifically for java?
For eg:
package com.khush.distributed.cache;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cache cache = new Cache(4);
        cache.put("1", "1");
        cache.put("2", "2");
        cache.put("3", "3");
        cache.put("4", "4");
        cache.printList();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        
        cache.get("2");
        cache.printList();
        
        cache.put("5", "5");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        cache.printList();
    }
}

When i try to run this. it can't find the Cache class because obviously it is not compiled (ps: Cache class is in the same package)
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Cache cache = new Cache(4);
        ^
  symbol:   class Cache
  location: class Main
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Cache cache = new Cache(4);
                          ^
  symbol:   class Cache
  location: class Main
2 errors

[Process exited 1]

how can i fix this? here is my .lua config that i am using for running the code
return {
    "CRAG666/code_runner.nvim",
    config = function()
        require("code_runner").setup({
            filetype = {
                java = {
                    "cd $dir &&",
                    "javac $fileName &&",
                    "java $fileNameWithoutExt",
                },
                python = "python3 -u",
                typescript = "deno run",
                rust = {
                    "cd $dir &&",
                    "rustc $fileName &&",
                    "$dir/$fileNameWithoutExt",
                },
            },
        })
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>r", ":RunCode<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = false })
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>rf", ":RunFile<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = false })
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>rp", ":RunProject<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = false })
    end,
}

apart from this plugin, i did try some other plugins aswell but i am not really that good with setting things up yet,
Any help with this is appreciated, thank you.

its been years since I've touched java, but don't you have to provide a classpath when you run java file?

In your case to run correctly it should be like:
java -classpath target/classes com.khush.distributed.cache.Main

But it's wrong to run like
java com.khush.distributed.cache.Main

as your package not saved as class path location that is very important, as class loader will try to find class in exactly same dir path, you need to move it to right directory, or just remove package at all, and in this case you can recompile class and then run just by
java Main

or as you compiled it directly in src/main/java, with package, you can just run it as it is from root (it will be working only in case dev directory, not prod jar of course, because of that, I highly not recommend this approatch)
java -classpath src/main/java/ com.khush.distributed.cache.Main

In case CRAG666/code_runner.nvim can be
java = {
       "java -classpath src/main/java/",
       "$(grep '^package' $dir/$fileName | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/;//').$fileNameWithoutExt"
                },

But I highly recomment to use Maven or Gradle for similar purposes! See below

MAVEN
In case maven or gradle if you are using them to run java app only one problem - speed , they very slow to run simple main method during development process. They are great package managers, but to simple run, nothing better than simple java -cp class_name, same using by IntelliJ actually. Only think we need to resolve - full app class path of full dependencies, and maven and gradle resolving it very easily.
I will show basic idea on maven, but the same can be used easily for gradle or another managers of course
In case maven, I'm using next command in my CRAG666/code_runner.nvim config (but with caching classpath script, see below)
return {
    "CRAG666/code_runner.nvim",
    config = function()
        require('code_runner').setup({
            filetype = {
                java = {
                    "java -classpath $(mvn -o -q dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=/dev/stdout -DincludeScope=runtime):target/classes",
                    "$(grep '^package' $dir/$fileName | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/;//').$fileNameWithoutExt"
                },
            },
        })
        vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rr', ':RunCode<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false, desc = "Run Code" })
    end
}


First line build java -classpath [full class path to run with your class]
Second build correct full class file package path with main() method like com.something.project.api.ApplicationRun to correctly run it


SPEED UP & CACHING CLASS PATH
If you want speed up next runs (as maven by itself not very fast to any operations, but we need run code very offten and not want to wait every time couple seconds more), you can for example add simple script to cache full class path result, and refresh only in case your pom.xml was changed, in this case all runs will be blazingly fast!
for example in my config I have next to achieve it:
java = {
     "java -classpath $($HOME/dotfiles/work/java/mvn_cp_cache.sh):target/classes",
     "$(grep '^package' $dir/$fileName | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/;//').$fileNameWithoutExt"
},

bash script mvn_cp_cache.sh
#!/bin/bash

CACHE_FILE=".classpath.cache"
POM_FILE="pom.xml"

if [ ! -f "$CACHE_FILE" ] || [ "$POM_FILE" -nt "$CACHE_FILE" ]; then
    if [ -f $CACHE_FILE ]; then
        rm $CACHE_FILE
    fi
    mvn -q dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile="$CACHE_FILE" -DincludeScope=runtime
fi

cat $CACHE_FILE

don't forget chmod +x mvn_cp_cache.sh and add .classpath.cache to git ignore 
The same idea can be applied to gradle (just class path build command will be $(./gradlew printClasspath -q)).
Actually you can just extend script to check if presents pom.xml or build.gradle/kt etc and run appropriate command to build  classpath to cache
In result, doesn't matter what java app you are running, simple main or spring boot app etc, run will be all time correct and work in any java app and any java project you want. And it's VERY fast! I'm using it a lot during my workflow.
For example IntelliJ Idea to run java code using similar idea 

I use neovim as my java IDE too.Is not recommend using code runner plugin to run java file or project. My suggestion is to use a packaging tool like Maven or Gradle. If you use Maven, just configure maven-assemble-plugin or maven-shade-plugin in pom.xml then simply run:
mvn clean package && java -jar /path/to/*.jar 

in terminal. If you use Gradle, run:
gradle run 

in terminal.
